# C# compiler error CS0433

Tags: c#, unit-testing, windows-8, visual-studio-2012

Update 1: I have uploaded my project folder to dropbox - [dropbox.com/s/8dfw3uprrynrhzx/S3Util.zip](http://dropbox.com/s/8dfw3uprrynrhzx/S3Util.zip)

I am new to Visual Studio, and I have created a small Windows Runtime Component in C# on Visual Studio 2012 Express for Windows 8.

My component consists of a single sealed class, with a single static method. I have added a unit test library project to the solution to test this static method.

(I followed [this walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182532.aspx) to create a unit test)

When I build the solution, I get the following error:

> Error  1       The type 'S3Util.S3Security' exists in both 'c:\workspace\vs\S3Util\S3Util\bin\Debug\S3Util.winmd' and 'c:\workspace\vs\S3Util\S3Util\bin\Debug\S3Util.winmd'
>   C:\workspace\vs\TestLib_S3Util\TestLib_S3Util\Test_Security.cs  18  27  TestLib_S3Util

The [error help page on Microsoft website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28CS0433%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETCore) indicates that it is a Compiler Error CS0433.

However, my unit test library contains only one reference to my windows runtime component project, and even the error message I see is referring to the same *.winmd* file twice. Kindly help me understand the issue and how to resolve it.

Error screenshot: (click for full size)

[image]

Comment: My guess is that is a Visual Studio bug. Try deleting all the files in your bin and obj folders (either manually through Windows Explorer or via the Clean Solution option in Visual Studio). You might want to also want to restart VS after deleting these files too.

Comment: I don't really know what that error could be referring to but could it be that you're referencing different versions of your library? Perhaps you are referencing a compiled dll and not your existing project?

Comment: Thank you for the response Hector. I deleted all the files in bin and obj folders, restarted Visual Studio and tried to build the solution again, but I still get the same error. Perhaps, as you said, it is a Visual Studio bug. I am trying to get in touch with the Microsoft team.

Comment: @Jeff - I am sure I am not referencing a compiled dll, because when I add a reference in the unit test project, I can see that I am adding S3Util.csproj in the Reference Manager dialog

Comment: Would it be possible to zip the project and add it to for instance a public dropbox for others to try it?

Comment: How does your Line 18 look like in Test_Security.cs?

Comment: @Default - Thank you for the suggestion. I have uploaded my project at -https://www.dropbox.com/s/8dfw3uprrynrhzx/S3Util.zip

Comment: @Default - Line 18 in Test_Security.cs is -> String hash = S3Security.HMACSHA1(key, data);

Comment: Have you tried making S3Security static instead of sealed? Unfortunately without Windows 8 I can only tell so much.

Answer (score 1):

In cases when I don't know why the error occurs I'm starting to narrow the list of possibilities. I'd do the following:

1. Look for a class S3Security via search. If you find 2 of them - remove one.
2. Try to remove one of the references were added recently and compile. Remove till the project compiles.
3. Try to remove latest files/projects untill solution compiles with no error. You can also try a reverse move, start to do the stes you were doing and check at which step you will get your error. Let us know what is it.

Comment: Thank you for the response, Yaroslav.
1. This is my first and only project in Visual Studio, hence I don't find another S3Security in my workspace
2. The only reference I added a reference to S3Util project, and I added it to my unit test project.
3. There are only 2 files in the project, once .cs for my S3Util class, and one .cs file for my unit test

Comment: @AnilRaj how about changing the name of a class from S3Security to something else? It will complain against the new name or it`s the only name that is treated like that?

Comment: I just tried that too, but I keep getting the same error (with the new class name)

Comment: Ok, it seems a compiler error. If by changing the class you are getting same kind of error, but with the new class name - it`s compiler error. I could not open the project to test it out as don`t have this version of Visual Studio.

Comment: It is a compiler error. However, I could not understand the error because it says the type exists in 'File1' and 'File2', where both File1 and File2 point to the same file.